# Large BLOB getting from SQLiteDatabase in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, crop

Here, I am currently working in a project which is include Image getting from Gallery or Camera & Crop this image after store in database. It's work perfectly. But When image size is large then it's store in database perfectly but when getting this image from database it's give s error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Convert Bitmap to byte Array

```
public byte[] bitmpToByte(Bitmap bmp)
 {
     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
     byte[] imgarray = stream.toByteArray();
     return  imgarray;
 }
```

Store this byte array in database.

```
values.put("blob_image", imgArray); // byte[] imgArray;
```

Getting from database & convert to bitmap & display.

```
    Record helper = new Record getActivity());
    Database database = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(Const.TABLE_NAME1, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor != null) {

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        id = String.valueOf(cursor.getString(0));
        com_name.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        byte[] imgArray= cursor.getBlob(2);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgArray , 0, imgArray.length);
        displayImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    try {
        cursor.close();
        helper.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

So, How to store & retrieve large size image from database?

Comment: No issue is about your `Cursor` not for `Image`.. check your Cursor and post more code.

Comment: @MD Please Check this code.

Comment: @JS check it `if(cursor.moveToFirst())` and fetch value from cursor

Comment: if moveToFirst() return true, then try to access the data, otherwise don't

Comment: i try with but still this error getting. @MD

Comment: @JigarShekh How you tried?> post your code

Comment: if(cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {} @MD

Comment: @JigarShekh try as per my answer....

Comment: i try with but still this error getting. @MahmoudElmorabea

Comment: Your are passing null as the second param, which is the columns to retrieve .. that's why no columns return

Comment: here it's work perfectly but when i update this row with large blob (image) update successfully. But when i try to retrieve after update filed it's gives error. @MahmoudElmorabea

Comment: After update it's give error. @MahmoudElmorabea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check `cursor.moveToFirst()` then only you access the `Cursor` Data.like

```
 Cursor cursor = database.query(Const.TABLE_NAME1, null, null, null, null, null, null);

do{
  if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {

  //Do your job

 }
}while(cursor.moveToNext());

 cursor.close();
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it. this error getting

Comment: @JigarShekh try with `.rawQuery(....)` like `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + Const.TABLE_NAME1, null);` and you make sure that your TABLE_NAME1 is not `NULL`